# python ads /%0A when read url from file

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

My first python and stackoverflow attempt.

reading a url from a variable eg

```py
url = 'http://google.com/'
```

for using with requests works.
But when i load a line using open e.g.

```py
...  
  with open('001aTOz.txt', 'r') as f:
        for link in f:
            lineCounter += 1
            if lineCounter == printline:
                url = (f.readline())
                Get_ip()
```

the line (url) ads some weird text to the end from the line

```py
def Check_ip():
        resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=3)
        print(resp.url)
        ...
```

Output

```
http://google.com/%0A
Request to http://google.com/
 timed out
```

so

```
resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=3)
```

works from a variable in the code
but adds `%0A` when i try to read it from a file

any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%0A` is an ASCII character for newline, which ends a line in a text file. You have to remove it before your requests, for example with [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
with open('001aTOz.txt', 'r') as f:
    for link in f:
        url = link.strip()
        resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=3)
        print(resp.url)
```